# programmatically access IME

Tags: nlp

Is there a way to access Japanese or chinese IME either from the command line or python? I have Linux/osx/win8 boxes, so which ever system exposes the easiest accessible api is fine.

I'm experimenting with building a Japanese kana-kanji conversion algorithm and would like to establish a baseline using existing tools. I also have some collections of kana I would like to process.

Preferably I would like something along the lines of

```
$ ime JP "きしゃのきしゃがきしゃできしゃした"
貴社の記者が汽車で帰社した
```

I've looked at anthy, mozc and dbus on Linux but can't find anyway to interact with them via the terminal or scripting (such as python)

Comment: Not quite what you want, but [http://www.google.com/transliterate?langpair=ja-Hira%7Cja&text=にゅうりょくつーるをしたからえらんでにゅうりょくをはじめてください。](http://www.google.com/transliterate?langpair=ja-Hira%7Cja&text=%E3%81%AB%E3%82%85%E3%81%86%E3%82%8A%E3%82%87%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A4%E3%83%BC%E3%82%8B%E3%82%92%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%81%88%E3%82%89%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AB%E3%82%85%E3%81%86%E3%82%8A%E3%82%87%E3%81%8F%E3%82%92%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%80%82) The first entry for each word is google's best guess.

Comment: It is definitely the functionality I'm looking for, but I am not sure how reliable the service is. Will I be blocked after 100s of request like Google text to speech?
I would prefer to interface with the software that is already on my machine.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is purely about programming.

Answer (score 0):

## Anthy provides a cli tool

Personally, I prefer google's *IME* / *mozc* for better results, but perhaps this helps.

The source for anthy ([sourceforge](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/anthy/releases/37536), file `anthy-9100h.tar.gz`) includes a simple cli program for testing. Download the source file, extract it, run

```
./configure && make
```

Enter the directory `test` which contains the binary `anthy`. By default, it reads from `test.txt` and uses EUC_JP encoding.

Simple test:

Input file `test.txt`

```
*にほんごにゅうりょく
*もももすももももものうち。
```

Run (using `iconv` to convert to UTF-8:

```
./anthy --all  | iconv -f EUC-JP -t UTF-8
```

Output:

```
1:(にほんごにゅうりょく)
|にほんご|にゅうりょく
にほんご(日本語:(1,1000,N,72089)2500,001 ,にほんご:(N,0,-)2 ,ニホンゴ:(N,0,-)1 ,):
にゅうりょく(入力:(1,1000,N,62394)2500,001 ,にゅうりょく:(N,0,-)2 ,ニュウリョク:(N,0,-)1 ,):

2:(もももすももももものうち。)
|ももも|すももも|もものうち|。
ももも(桃も:(,1000,Ny,72089)225,279 ,ももも:(N,1000,Ny,72089)220,773 ,モモも:(,1000,Ny,72089)205,004 ,腿も:(,1000,Ny,72089)204,722 ,股も:(,1000,Ny,72089)146,431 ,モモモ:(N,0,-)1 ,):
すももも(すももも:(N,1000,Ny,72089)202,751 ,スモモも:(,1000,Ny,72089)168,959 ,李も:(,1000,Ny,72089)168,677 ,スモモモ:(N,0,-)1 ,):
もものうち(桃のうち:(,1000,N,655)2,047 ,もものうち:(N,1000,N,655)2,006 ,モモのうち:(,1000,N,655)1,863 ,腿のうち:(,1000,N,655)1,861 ,股のうち:(,1000,N,655)1,331 ,モモノウチ:(N,0,-)1 ,):
。(。:(1N,100,N,70203)57,040 ,.:(1,100,N,70203)52,653 ,．:(1,100,N,70203)3,840 ,):
```

You can uncomment some `printf` statements in the source files [`test/main.c`](http://pastebin.com/p6dBtm41) and [`src-main/context.c`](http://pastebin.com/8QVSkM7v) to make the output more readable/parsable, eg:

```
1   にほんごにゅうりょく
にほんご    日本語
にゅうりょく  入力

2   もももすももももものうち。
ももも 桃も
すももも    すももも
もものうち   桃のうち
。   。
```